# Django CONN_MAX_AGE setting error

Tags: python, django

I'm getting `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'` when trying to set `CONN_MAX_AGE` in Django 1.6.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
        'NAME': 'myDB',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
        'HOST': '',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': '60',  # seconds for persistent connection, since Django 1.6
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unlike the `PORT`, provide the `CONN_MAX_AGE` setting as an integer (not as a string):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
        'NAME': 'myDB',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
        'HOST': '',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 60,  # seconds for persistent connection, since Django 1.6
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```